# Group the ones according to their positions using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix in MATALB with `{0, 1}` entries. I want to collect the ones `1` in groups following these rules:

- I start by any `1` in the matrix and I put it in, say, `group1`.
- After I go and see if there are ones in the corresponding row and column. If so, I add all ones from that row and column to `group1`.
- Each time I found a one in the row or in the column I go and I see the corresponding row and column and I add the ones to that group (`group1`).
- If I do not find any other one in the corresponding row or column I will go to the next group, say, `group2`
- I continue like this until no one is found in the matrix.

Here I give a simple example:

```
A = [ 1 0 0 1 0
      1 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 1 0
      0 0 0 1 0 
      0 1 1 0 0 ]

group1 = {(1, 1)}
% I put in group1 the first element A(1, 1) (arbitrarly)
% Since in row 1 and column 1 we have A(1, 4) = 1 and A(2, 1) = 1 so I 
% add them to group1
group1 = {(1, 1), (1, 4), (2, 1)}
% We see now that I have no one that correspond to the element A(2, 1) since 
% A(2, :) = 0 and A(:, 1) = 0. But I have ones that correspond to element A(1, 4) 
% which are A(3, 4) and A(4, 4) so I add them to group1
group1 = {(1, 1), (1, 4), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 4)}
% Also A(3, 4) and A(4, 4) have no corresponding ones. Hence I stop and I go to group2
group2 = {(5, 2)}
% I do the same and I get:
group1 = {(1, 1), (1, 4), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 4)}
group2 = {(5, 2), (5, 3)}
```

What I thought of is something like this:

```
for i = 1:size(A, 1)
   e{i} = find(A(i, :)~=0);
end
for j = 1:size(A, 1)
   for i = e{j}
      a{i} = find(A(:, i)~=0);
   end
end
```

Any suggestions please? Can I do it without loops?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to solve similar problems in the past (mainly for solving certain kinds of logical puzzles), I always found it easiest to keep a stack/set of points that you still need to look at, and process them one by one until the stack is empty.

Written in [pseudocode](https://www.python.org/), this is pretty easy:

```
groups = []
while any_points_left(A):
    group = []
    stack = [pick_random_point(A)]
    while not_empty(stack):
        p = stack.pop()
        group.append(p)
        mark_as_done(p)
        for q in all_points_in_same_row_or_column(p):
            stack.append(q)
    groups.append(group)
```

Translated to Matlab (which is not the ideal language for this kind of code):

```
groups = {};
while nnz(A) > 0 % any points left?
    % find random point
    [i, j] = ind2sub(size(A), find(A, 1, 'first'));
    stack = {[i, j]};
    group = {};
    while ~isempty(stack)
        p = stack{end}; stack = stack(1:end-1); % pop point from stack
        i = p(1); j = p(2);
        if A(i, j) == 0 % check if point is not already removed
            continue
        end
        A(i, j) = 0; % mark as done   
        group{end+1} = p; % add to group

        for ii = 1:size(A, 1) % check same column
            if A(ii, j) == 1
                stack{end+1} = [ii, j]; % add to stack
            end
        end        
        for jj = 1:size(A, 2) % check same row
            if A(i, jj) == 1
                stack{end+1} = [i, jj]; % add to stack
            end
        end
    end
    groups{end+1} = group;
end

% print result
for ig = 1:length(groups)
    fprintf('Group %i: ', ig)
    group = groups{ig};
    for ip = 1:length(group)
        fprintf('(%i, %i) ', group{ip}(1), group{ip}(2))
    end
    fprintf('\n')
end
```

It should be possible to write this code a bit more compact at the cost of clarity. Result:

```
Group 1: (1, 1) (1, 4) (4, 4) (3, 4) (2, 1) 
Group 2: (5, 2) (5, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Image Processing toolbox, one approach would be to create segments that contain all the ones in a given row or column. Here is an example with your matrix:

First, pad the array with a border of zeros:

```
Apad=padarray(A, [1,1], 0, 'both');
```

Then perform a morphological closing on this array with horizontal and vertical lines:

```
se1 = strel('line',3,0);
se2 = strel('line',3,90);
closedA = imclose(Apad,se1);
closedA = imclose(closedA,se2);
```

Get rid of the border pixels,

```
Segments=closedA(2:end-1, 2:end-1);
```

The results is:

```
Segments =

     1     1     1     1     0
     1     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     1     1     0     0
```

You can then extract connected components:

```
CC = bwconncomp(Segments,4);
```

And loop along the groups and identify the pixels in `A` that are contained in each group:

```
LinIndices=find(A);
for k=1:CC.NumObjects
   Pixels{k}=LinIndices(ismember(LinIndices, CC.PixelIdxList{k}))
end
```

The pixels are now grouped in the array `Pixels`, each cell contains the linear index of the pixels in a given group:

```
Pixels{1}= [1 2 16 18 19]

Pixels{2}= [10 15]
```

Graphically:

```
A(Pixels{1})=1
A(Pixels{2})=2

A =

     1     0     0     1     0
     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     2     2     0     0
```

**Note** the size of the structuring elements `se1` and `se2` must be optimized to the maximal distance between to isolated pixels. See [this other answer by @Bentoy13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23113581/2777181) for an alternative way of joining the segments.

Comment: Nice solution; I think you don't have to loop along the connected components, see my answer how to do this.

Comment: While answering your comment, I have an idea: if you take the negative of A, I think you can perform the opening (instead of closing) of it with your structuring elements without having to take a border around A. And then negate the result. What do you think?

Comment: Same comment as with Bentoy's answer: I think this algorithm fails on the matrix `A = [0,1,0;1,0,1;0,1,0]`. According to the requirements (at least how I read them), this should produce two separated groups `{(2, 1), (2, 3)}` and `{(1, 2), (3, 2)}`.

Comment: @BasSwinckels might be that I misunderstood OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Following the idea of [@Jigg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23112528/1507014), I propose another very similar solution.

Locate, for each row and column, the first and the last indexes where there is a 1. Fill the segment between these two indexes with ones in another matrix:

```
B = zeros(size(A));
for i=1:size(A,1)
    m1 = find(A(i,:),1,'first');
    m2 = find(A(i,:),1,'last');
    B(i,m1:m2) = 1;
end
for i=1:size(A,2)
    m1 = find(A(:,i),1,'first');
    m2 = find(A(:,i),1,'last');
    B(m1:m2,i) = 1;
end
```

(There may be a shorter way to do that thing ...)

Then label all connected components of the new array B, and mask it with the array A:

```
Result = bwlabel(A,4).*A;
```

Comment: Great! I wanted to find a way to fill the segments without loops, but it's probably neater than using `imclose`.

Comment: @Jigg I think the problem with `imclose` is that the border must have a size related to the size of the structuring element, since I think that the exterior is assumed to be 0. And the structuring element has a length of `size(A,1)-2` (resp. `size(A,2)-2`) if you want to cover all cases. I'm a big fan of `bwmorph`, but here it's a hammer against a nut ... :)

Comment: I think this algorithm fails on the matrix `A = [0,1,0;1,0,1;0,1,0]`, since B in your algorithm will contain one connected cross. According to the requirements (at least how I read them), this should produce two separated groups `{(2, 1), (2, 3)}` and `{(1, 2), (3, 2)}`.

Comment: @BasSwinckels Argh you got me ... search for another solution.